# Rubymine tips for web rails developers

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ide, rubymine

I am transitioning in a web development role using rails.

I am using Rubymine as the IDE and I guess many of the web developers like it. What are your favorite short-cuts/tips/plugins/features that you really use for Rails/JS dev etc. Using IDE to full power is very useful for web developers

(Using OS-X 10.5+ binding)

Simple ones I like and am using so far:

```
ctrl+shift+o: Open File 
ctrl 0: Open class
cmd+1: Hide/Show Project Pane
ctrl+shift+f: Search entire project
ctrl+e: recently open file lists
cmd+7: Type hierarchy like eclipse
```

One shortcut/feature per answer

Answer (score 2):

Did you check this: http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/docs/RubyMine_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf

My favourites:

- cmd+b : jump to declaration
- shift+f6 : refactor->rename
- cmd+shift+T : jump to test-file or back

Answer (score 1):

- cmd+k: Commit changes to version control
- ctrl+t: refactor
- ctrl+option+t: surround with live template (context sensitive)
- cmd+.: <%= %> in ERB file
- ctrl+b: jump to method or class declaration

PS - not doing one per answer!